# Install a program from another program

Tags: c++, installation

I'm a game developer and my current task is to create a game launcher. If you know what is Battle.net, you'll understand what I mean. For the launcher itself we're using the InstallBuilder from Bitrock. But the end user should have a possibility to install actual game pressing a button in the launcher. The launcher then will download files, register them, show progress bar, allow to play a game before full download, create a shortcut etc. - the same way as Battle.net launcher behave.

So, my question - where to start? I suppose that this is platform specific, so for now I'm interested in Windows. I'm using VS2013, Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you must create an installer which will handle the actual installation of the application. You can then call the installer from your other process (in your case the launcher.)

In Qt you can use the `QProcess` Class which is documented [here.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html) I think that the documentation is really good and will answer most of your questions but what you need to do more or less is this:

```
QObject *parent;
...
QString program = "./path/to/your/installer";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-option" << "argument";

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

(Copied pretty much verbatim for the documentation.)

You also have the option of interacting with your installer after its execution start (you can for example read the exit code) so that you can monitor the installation progress form your launcher.

Comment: This is good news that I can use third-party installer with my case. And as I understand I need to find such installer that allows to track process, right?

Comment: @nikitablack You have a lot of options here ranging from a simple batch script to using something like Inno Setup. It really depends on what you want to install.